# Dataflow uploading files to /var/opt/google/dataflow/dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

This issue just started happening 5/9/18...

Dataflow is not able to find files packaged with my classes. I use Class.getResource("/data.json"). Stackdriver log shows it's looking for the file in /var/opt/google/dataflow/class-name.jar!/data.json. When I ssh into the VM instance for the worker, the file is actually in /var/opt/google/dataflow/dataflow/class-name.jar. This was working yesterday.

More information 5/11/18:
I just tested with the WordCount example straight from Apache Beam documentation:
https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/

Followed all the steps. Then added a "resources/data.json" to "src/main". Added the following lines to WordCount.ExtractWordsFn's processElement method:

```
    try {
      String jsonStr = new Scanner(new File(WordCount.class.getResource("/data.json").getFile())).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
      System.out.println("====================================================");
      System.out.println(jsonStr);
      System.out.println("====================================================");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Sure enough, got the same error in stack driver:

message:  "java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/var/opt/google/dataflow/classes-yGX0uczTTR8A8LXakSr0JA.jar!/data.json (No such file or directory)"

While the example batch is still running, I ssh'ed into the worker instance and checked /var/opt/google/dataflow. There is another "dataflow" directory, and the files are copied there. So confirmed the double dataflow directory issue.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Going to submit this issue in Github.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a workaround: use Class.getResourceAsStream to get an inputstream. For whatever reason, getResourceAsStream functioned as expected, while getResource still fails. For all of my purposes, an inputstream works just as well as a URL.

Comment: Have you submitted the issue on Class.getResource in Github? That seems to be the right thing to do.